# Is it more efficient on a server to load HTML templates from a file or from a Mongodb record?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My current setup is on a NodeJS server and loads HTML templates from files. I'm making some changes to my coding, and I'm wondering if part of that change should be to move the templates from individual files to database records.

Comment: It depends: What web server, db server, network connection, file sizes, number of requests, number of files, caching strategies, ... It is probably the best to measure it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

it depends: whether you need the end-user to change them or not,
for example, I was having static templates for sending emails, and I had to save them on the DB, and create a way for the user to change them without touching the code, but if there is no action on them then you can put them on the node server.
another approach is using S3 instead of DB for the static files.